# Angular 7: *ngFor with a component and passing variable parameters

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a portfolio item  that is being used in a parent component, web-portfolio.html, getting data from web-portfolio.ts.

I'm trying to pass  data from an array in the web-portfolio.ts file in an *ngFor loop.

```
<app-portfolio *ngFor = "let site of this.sites" name = "site.name" img = "site.img" description = "site.description" link = "site.link"></app-portfolio>
```

The app-portfolio component has inputs for these:

```
export class PortfolioComponent implements OnInit {

  isOpen: boolean = false;
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() img: string;
  @Input() description: string;
  @Input() link: string;

}
```

But instead of getting the correct output, I receive three of the initial array's value;

```
export class WebPortfolioComponent implements OnInit {
 sites = [
    {
     "name":"Site A",
     "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
      "img":"/web/sitea.png",
      "link":"http://sitea.com"
    },
    {
     "name":"Site B",
     "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
      "img":"/web/siteb.png",
      "link":"http://siteb.com"
    },
   {
     "name":"Site C",
     "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
      "img":"/web/siteC.png",
      "link":"http://siteC.com"
    },
  ];
}

 // OUTPUT => Blank, blank, blank
```

What am I doing wrong?

portfolio.component.html:

```
<div class = "portfolio-item">
  <div class = "portfolio-thumb">
    <a (click) = "this.isOpen = !this.isOpen">
      <img src = "" alt = ""/>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class = "portfolio-full" [ngClass] = "{'port-show':this.isOpen}">
    <div class = "portfolio-full-image" (click) = "this.isOpen = !this.isOpen">
      <img src = "{{this.img}}">
      <div class = "portfolio-description">
        {{this.description}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share the HTML code of `PortfolioComponent`.

Comment: Is it a typo to write `name` not `[name]`?

Comment: Neither name nor [name] seems to work. Which is correct, [name]? @pindev

Comment: @Samuel Done. Looks like originally there were images and alt text in there; now I just get three blanks.

Comment: It should be either `name="{{ site.name }}"` or `[name]="site.name"`

Comment: Your code looks correct when you change your html code as @pindev's comment. I was wondering whether the value of  `sites` was changed somewhere. Try to write `<p>{{ sites | json }}</p>` in your html to print out the value of it. And you don't need to write `this.` in html. You can just use `img`, `name` and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add {{}} for property component `name = "{{site.name}}"`

```
<app-portfolio *ngFor = "let site of this.sites" name = "{{site.name}}" 
 img = "{{site.img}}" description = "site.description" link = "site.link"></app-portfolio>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ns1qli

Update for your HTML still worked

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-parameter?file=src/app/portfolio.html

Comment: That doesn't seem to make any difference, unfortunately

Comment: Looks like I'd made a mistake leaving out the image src in the HTML. Thank you for your demo!

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the component like property binding in Angular

```
<app-portfolio *ngFor = "let site of this.sites" [name] = "site.name" [img] = "site.img" [description] = "site.description" [link] = "site.link"></app-portfolio>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `img` is an html attribute so it cannot be used with `@Input` so please use `[image]` instead, please check the below example.

<kbd>**Stack Blitz Demo**</kbd>